# Regarding Azure pricing

Tags: azure

Hi guy a bit of strange one.

I have started working with a developer/designer who builds websites for my clients. I pay him a fee for the website and then he charges me a monthly fee for the hosting/maintenance.

Now we charge the customer £15/month for the hosting.

My developer/designer has asked for £7.50/month for hosting + a 1 off fee of £5 to add the website to his server claiming it costs him £5 for every website he adds to the server.

My question is does it cost him £5 extra for every website he adds to the the server or not? He hosts the websites using Azure cloud.

I always thought you paid for the web server and you could then upload as many website as you like as long as it does not go over your bandwidth or free space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about business relations rather than programming

Comment: @darkowl - why should ivan move on? The question is off-topic, and you then accepted an answer that is just someone's guess (and goes on to describe how App Service plans are billed, when you don't even know if that's what your hoster is using). Plus you mentioned 1-off (one-time?) fees for adding websites, which is completely unrelated to Azure (so now it becomes a question of whether some human being should be allowed to earn  £5 for their efforts to add an additional site.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Azure Web Apps as you have stated in your description, you would pay per App Service Plan. Of course this may not be the case, and your hoster may have additional costs which he may be passing on to you.

In specific cases, if you're hosting multiple web sites on a set amount of servers, the cost doesn't increase for each app, however there will be a degradation in performance, and at some point you will obviously have to increase the amount of servers the apps are hosted on. There may be additional costs for other resources as well.

Specifically for Azure Web Apps an App Service Plan is a mapping from sites to servers. So you can have a large amount of small apps running on a couple of servers, or a small amount of large apps running on the same couple of servers. Provided that your App Service Plan is the same SKU and there are the same amount of instances in each, these will be the same cost.

That's why the billing page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/ has unlimited for the number of web apps. So to answer your question (if you are indeed using web apps), you will get billed for one App Service Plan (which may contain multiple servers) regardless of the number of apps you have in it, since regardless of the number of apps, you'll be using the same amount of servers.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: If it helps, then accept it or upvote it.

Comment: All done, again thank you. So in your opinion does it sound like he might be lying to me about the extra £5 charge? I have passed him 7 clients so far all paying a monthly subscription.

Comment: I'm going to refrain from commenting about the business relation, but the current payment structure of Azure App Service does not charge for additional apps. On the other hand, if you keep on adding more apps, at some point you're going to have to increase the number of servers in the ASP which will cost more.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Comment: @theadriangreen - First: You're answering an off-topic (pricing question). That aside: You jumped to the assumption the hoster is using Azure Websites. You then jumped to the assumption the hoster places each web site in the same app service plan. And that it doesn't need to be scaled up to a larger tier to properly support traffic from more than one site. And the OP mentioned a 1 off (which sounds like one-time) site addition fee (which has nothing to do with Azure). And you've assumed the hoster takes on no additional management cost. Basically this is just an opinion / best guess.

Comment: @DavidMakogon good points. I'm unable to delete my answer, so I've edited to qualify the specific scenario that I interpreted the problem as.